# JavaScript Date.getFullYear() returnin Nan - ONLY in FireFox

Tags: javascript, date, nan

So, I have a line of code:

```
endYear = new Date(job['end_date']).getFullYear();
```

where `job['end_date']` evaluates to `'Dec 2015'`.

In Chrome, Opera and Edge, this evaluates to `2015`. In FireFox (both regular and develop edition), it evaluates to `NaN`.

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: "Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."
[Found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: That is not a valid date string in JavaScript. Use this instead `endYear=job['end_date'].split(' ')[1]`

Comment: Thanks, both, fell free to post an answer. @Found, I was going to go with `split()`, but just wanted to hear an explanation from the pros ;-)